# Allow user to change views template

Tags: views

I have a view configured with a custom template. Now I need to represent the same information arranged in two different ways. What I want is for the user to have an option to change between the three different templates. This doesn't seem to out of the ordinary but I am having trouble finding an example.

Using Drupal 7.

Comment: Which views template are you using?  I'm sure you know, but there are quite a few templates that could be used to modify the output of a view.

Comment: If these are page views, eg `www.example.com/path/to/view`, you could set up multiple page displays, eg, `www.example.com/path/to/view/viewed/differently` and `www.example.com/path/to/view/viewed/another/way` and then have templates for each page display that display it however you want.  Of course, it would be up to you to include links to those other paths on your page, but I hope that's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I would build the different displays as separate blocks and then use the quicktab module.

https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs

That way, it will be very easy to switch between the blocks.

Configuration in quicktabs:

[image: Configuration in quicktabs]

Results:

[image: Tab1]

[image: Tab2]